# SQL, primary key, foreign key and table

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

If you have a table with a primary key and bunch of attributes, and three of those attributes are foreign keys coming from other tables, then how do you describe the functional dependencies in this type of table?

So if you have ID as primary key and id1, id2, id3 and other column names like name, address etc. where id1, id2 and id3 are foreign keys, will it look something like this? ID(id1, id2, id3, name, address....) where all of these are FD to ID?

Answer (score 1):

You express functional dependencies by creating foreign key constraints on the concerned columns that referrence the column they depend on in the other tables.

Example:

```
create table mytable (
    id int primary key,
    id1 int,
    id2 int,
    id3 int,
    name varchar(50),
    address varchar(250),
    foreign key (id1) references table1(id),
    foreign key (id2) references table2(id),
    foreign key (id3) references table3(id)
);
```

Comment: Ok so in this table only name and addeess are functioanlly dependent to primary key ID?